# Wildlfy server slow issue

Tags: javascript, jboss

Suddenly Wildfly server is getting slow. Buffering will be done only if the user calls the URL for the DMS application. Sometimes users call the URL, the front page comes up , then clicking on login with user id and password, it takes a long time to enter the DMS.Then we installed and configured a new wildfly and it work fine 1-2 month and now the same problem started. When wildfly server is getting slow then we checked in DB where every time the attacehd insert query goes to sleeping state,the query is given below.
query:

Please give me a proper solution.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: <?query --
insert into SX2142068428026784_DP (DOCNO,BMPPAGENO,PAGENO,VOLUMENO,BMPPAGEOFFSET,PAGESIZE,PAGETYPE,PAGEDESC,PSL,KEEPURL,BMPTHUMBOFFSET,THUMBSIZE,FILENAME,FILETYPE,UPLOAD_DATE,UPLOAD_TIME,UPLOAD_USER,MARKUPNAME,MARKUPTYPE,DOCTYPE) values (25070912,15729,1,1071,'e1e75e21822735a9c57caa0e6b2a29e4','09de69516b2b5d590132934e503723bff430928912ba2821',83,'#KS_9374835_AOF.PDF',0,0,'0303fb07160e427e6702f16eae4ced2f','2502b8c93242274c4832ab21e1c0af00','KS_9374835_AOF.pdf','pdf',convert(datetime,'04/01/2023',103),'16:12:48','JDOL$','','','DEFAULT')
--?>

Comment: which code you want?